# Microsoft Excel 2016 - how to join rows from another worksheet based on a matching text column

Tags: excel, join, match, excel-2016

I have two worksheets, each with a number of different columns. Both worksheets have a text column called 'Name' and some records (maybe 1%) have matching names in both worksheets. How can I join the rows from worksheet B to worksheet A for those records with matching names? The result would be the columns from worksheet B added to the end of worksheet A with the data from the matching records added in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe INDEX + MATCH can achieve what you want.

Assume you have two worksheets like the following:

Worksheet A

[image]

Worksheet B

[image]

The added data that shows in Worksheet A can be achieved by using a combination of Index + Match function.

For cell D3 the formula will look like:

```
=INDEX('Worksheet B'!$B$3:$B$8 ; MATCH('Worksheet A'!A3 ; 'Worksheet B'!$A$3:$A$8;0))
=INDEX(What you want to return ; MATCH(Lookup value; Which column it should look for the value ; if the match should be exact or not)
```

So in my example I want to return the work in worksheet B (Finance). I do this by looking at the name "Adam Smith" (worksheet A) and I will search for that name in worksheet B, name column.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. That worked the first time. However, I adapted the formula for another spreadsheet and keep getting the error: 'the syntax of this name isn't correct.' Do you have any ideas how I can solve this?I am using this formula: 
            =INDEX('Full'!A2:A20780, MATCH([@[Person]], 'Full’!J2:J20780,0))       in my worksheet A, where 'Full' is my worksheet B, from where I want to append data to matching entries in worksheet A, where names in the 'person' column match with names in column A in worksheet B.

Comment: Yes, I think I know. [@[Person]] refers to a Excel Table cell. But it seems strange, I'm used to [@Person]. Sometimes it's easier to change the [@Person] to a single cell you want to look up (ex. B2 or A3). So formula could look like: `=INDEX('Full'!A2:A20780,MATCH([@Person]; 'Full'!J2:J20780,0))` or `=INDEX('Full'!A2:A20780,MATCH(A8; 'Full'!J2:J20780,0))`. I also noticed that your `'` looks like `’`... could be an issue...

Comment: Two sides notices: 1. When you drag the formula `=INDEX('Full'!A2:A20780,MATCH([@Person]; 'Full'!J2:J20780,0))` it will change the `A2:A20780` for each row you drag. Let's say you have it in cell `A2`. If you drag it to Cell `A3` it will look: `=INDEX('Full'!A2:A20781,MATCH(A8; 'Full'!J2:J20781,0))`. Notice excel will automatically add 1 to 20780, becuase you haven't lock the formula (it's a relative formula). By adding `$A$2:$A$20780`, you will always look at this range no matter how you drag your formula... :)

Comment: 2. If you want to use table names (header in your table) as reference in your formula you could use something like this. ...... Assume that my example from the picture above has Worksheet A, which have "Table1" and in Worksheet B I have "Table2". Then the formula could look like this for Cell `D3`: `=INDEX(Table2[Work],MATCH([@Name],Table2[Name],0))`